# NullPointerException in Page Navigation

Tags: jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception

```
public String onClickSearchTaskTemplate(){
    RcentJsfUtils.setFlashValue("seqNo",getSeqNo());
    setUpdateButton(true);
    return "searchTaskTemplate";
}

public void init(){
    setUpdateButton(true);
Object obj = TemplateDAO.readbyId(Long.parseLong(RcentJsfUtils.getFlashValueForKey("seqNo").toString()));
}
```

Here inside the `init` method i get a null pointer exception but the method i am using is correct.

Comment: What is the question? What is the actual exception, with stack trace? What are the things in init()?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much any of those lines could be returning null. My guess offhand is that "seqNo" doesn't exist as a key, but there's really not enough information to say with any accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a bit more context and code if you want help. You should also break your long line (where the nullpointer exception is thrown) in multiple, smaller lines, so that you know for sure which variable is null.

At first glance, I would say that the error is probably happening because getFlashValueForKey("seqNo") is null. This might be because onClickSearchTaskTemplate() is not called before your init() method.